# Built app crashes on NoClassDefFoundError in Firebase aar files

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently facing a problem with Firebase plugins in Unity. When I start my Android app after building it, it instantly crashes with this error:

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider;
  at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents (DatabaseRegistrar.java:41)
  at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar (ComponentMonitor.java:28)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents (ComponentRuntime.java:117)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init> (ComponentRuntime.java:99)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init> (ComponentRuntime.java:46)
  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build (ComponentRuntime.java:387)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init> (FirebaseApp.java:438)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:295)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:263)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:248)
...
```

I looked at the aar files downloaded by the android dependencies resolver. I've got the following aar files:

- com.google.firebase.firebase-database-20.2.0.aar
- com.google.firebase.firebase-appcheck-interop-17.0.0.aar

[Classes found in com.google.firebasefirebase-appcheck-interop-17.0.0.aar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSCAd.png)

I can find a InteropAppCheckTokenProvider class but no InternalAppCheckTokenProvider.

I've got the last version (10.7.0) of the plugin in Unity 2021.3.11f1. I tried to install the plugins with both the .unitypackage files and the Package Manager, resulting in the same issue. Do I have the wrong versions of the plugins? Do I miss something? Or did I find a bug I should report to Firebase?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Had the same issue. In my case I was using the Firebase BOM dependency with a version and the app-check debug dependency with a different version - as soon as I used the app-check debug dependency with the same version of other Firebase deps, it worked

Comment: What's strange here is that I have the same version for every firebase plugin (10.7.0) and I triple checked I had every dependencies for com.google.firebase.database (auth, app and external-dependency-manager). Maybe I'll try to install an older version of the plugins and see if it results in the same error. Thanks for your help @CatalinGhita!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run **Force Resolve** in the Android Resolver does it succeed at resolution?

[image: The location of the option pictured.]

Try doing so and then building again.

If the issue continues, enable both **Custom Main Gradle Template** and **Custom Gradle Property template** in the Android Resolver settings and then try building and running again.

If issues persist, proceed through the debugging steps listed in this [build debug guide](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/main/build-and-debug-guide.md).

If all else fails then file a ticket on the firebase-unity-sdk github.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! The Force Resolve succeeds but then I still have the issue, I'll try the to enable the custom templates and then go through the step and see what happens!

Comment: Enabling **Custom Main Gradle Template** and **Custom Gradle Property** and then run another **Force Resolve** worked! Once again, thank you!